# How to print nth line of a function output

Tags: python, recursion, slice

How can I print nth line of output 'a'? I tried slicing 'a' but it doesn't work. I can't seem to iterate through 'a' too.

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = []
C = []

def move(n, pegA, pegB, pegC):
    if n > 0:
        move(n - 1, pegA, pegC, pegB)
        target.append(pegA.pop())
        print(len(A), len(B), len(C))
        move(n - 1, pegC, pegB, pegA)

a = move(3, A, C, B)
```

a returns the output below:

```
2 0 1
1 1 1
1 2 0
0 2 1
1 1 1
1 0 2
0 0 3
```

I would like be able to print say the 2nd line which is 1 1 1. Should I restructure the function 'move' instead?

Comment: have you tried keeping the output in a list and printing the desired position from that.

Comment: @manasdash i'd call that an anti-pattern in python. just `yield` and let the consumer decide

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion @user633183

Comment: @user633183: I agree that `yield` would probably be best for production code, but this doesn't look like production code to me. I would think conciseness and ease of understanding would be more important than performance and program architecture best practice, for OP and for people viewing this question in the future.

Comment: @lehiester it's not a performance thing; it's a matter of being able to use the result in any way other than `print`ing it...

Answer (score 1):

The way `move` is structured doesn't retain any record of the output it has printed, and it would be very difficult to recover.  If you need to look up lines of output by index, you could instead return a list with each line of output, like so:

```
def move(n, pegA, pegB, pegC, output_lines=None):
    if output_lines is None:
        output_lines = []
    if n > 0:
        move(n - 1, pegA, pegC, pegB, output_lines)
        target.append(source.pop())
        output_lines.append('%d %d %d' % (len(A), len(B), len(C)))
        move(n - 1, pegC, pegB, pegA, output_lines)
    return output_lines

a = move(3, A, C, B)

# print all lines of output
print('\n'.join(a))

# print 2nd line
print(a[1])
```

Comment: I would have suggested the much more elegant solution of actually using your return values instead of ignoring them. Having that input parameter acting like a global just feels weird.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: I don't know of a way to concatenate the output from each recursive call without making it scale worse than O(n), but maybe there's a way.  I agree it's ugly.

Comment: @lehiester. Yeah, there's always the unnecessary memory clobbering.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I believe this is the best solution. I can't think of a way to append to a "running total" list in recursive functions with only `return`s.

Comment: @Tomothy. You extend the list in the same order you make the calls. The issue is that it makes a whole lot of unnecessary copies along the way, instead of the normal amortized appends.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah, that's what I just thought of. It would be best to only have the original list modified, and that's what this answer does.

Comment: I think you could do it with a custom linked list implementation, but not with something in the Python standard library.

Comment: @wussyx: More information would be needed, but it would be best to create another question for it.